# How to find my answer on a now-closed question?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Last week I answered a question where someone more or less asked if using jQuery made someone a weaker JavaScript developer. The question did have some problems in how it was asked (it read more like an essay that advocated the point rather than an open question in the head of the asker), but I thought there were some worthwhile points to discuss regarding jQuery and JavaScript, so I wrote an answer.

The question was then closed, which was fair enough, but yesterday I went back to borrow some of what I wrote in another context, and I can't seem to find my answer now. It doesn't show up under my activity tab. It doesn't show up under my stats tab under the answers section.

Using either stackoverflow search or google search with my username and jQuery and JavaScript as keywords doesn't seem to yield anything relevant.

If you post an answer on a question that gets closed, is it lost forever? Or are there other tricks for finding them?

Comment: If you have the URL for the question, please paste it here (it might be in your browser history).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grace Note is correct. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130172/jquery-bad-for-your-brain-closed) is the deleted question, but of course you won't be able to read it until you reach 10k rep.

Here's the text of your answer:

> When you're writing jQuery, you're writing JavaScript. jQuery isn't a way of avoiding JavaScript the *language*, it's a way of avoiding the cumbersome JavaScript *DOM* (and the cross-browser incompatibility issues).
>
> I'm going to say that again, even though you probably got it the first time,  because a lot of people didn't. jQuery doesn't replace JavaScript. It replaces the DOM (thank heavens).
>
> Not only that, jQuery is such a great example of an abstraction which genuinely saves work that I suspect using it is a net positive contribution to a developer's education. JavaScript has probably done more than any other language to spread the concepts of first-class functions, anonymous functions, and closures around to the general engineering population, and jQuery's idioms are no small part of that.
>
> I do more or less agree that it's an educational experience to write plain ol' js, and I can see how jQuery's features and expressiveness make some formerly elaborate tasks so brief and simple that a lot of people can now cut and paste their way to functionality that you had to work really hard on five years ago. But that's the way of things: better abstractions put more power in your hands for less understanding, and let's face it, everybody in a software field who uses tools they didn't write makes this tradeoff all the time.

Comment: "jquery bad for your brain"? I can't read the question for lack of rep, but oy, I can see why it got closed...

Comment: @Grace Most of the post wasn't bad, although it contains the sentence "And I notice it melts people's brains".

Answer (score 3):

Answers to closed questions are no different than answers to open questions, in terms of access. All closing does is bar new answers from being posted.

What most likely happened is that the question has been deleted now, and your answer with it. This would explain the answer vanishing from your profile's list of answers. You may flag a post of yours for moderator attention and request someone to email you the content of the deleted answer. Without 10k, you can't see a deleted answer of yours if it's on a deleted question. And even with 10k, it's not easy to find.

Comment: It doesn't appear on the recently deleted list, so it must have been more than a couple of days ago.

Comment: @Jon Doesn't recently deleted list extend infinitely to the past? The answer was purportly provided about a week ago, so searching backwards up to, say, November 7th should confirm whether or not it was deleted. Or... a diamond could just check the profile. If one is available, that would be ideal.

Comment: @Grace - DOH! I had never realized that the 2D, etc filters apply.

Comment: @Jon Whoops, we're talking about two different recently deleted lists. Go figure.

Comment: @Grace - I only see back to 11/15 for recently deleted.

Comment: Yeah, unless he has the URL we'll need a diamond mod.

Comment: @Jon Did you check the recently deleted list under the Links tab? That should extend farther in the past, and also include answers (the Deleted tab only tracks questions not deleted by the question owner, which this might have been).

Comment: Wish I had a URL, but I just searched my history file pretty closely and didn't come up with anything. Also, while I think I answered the question last week sometime, I'm not sure of the day... it may have even been back to weekend before last (say, anywhere from the 6th on).